# How can one prove that this polynomial is non-negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry, sum-of-squares-method

How one can prove the following inequality?

$$58x^{10}-42x^9+11x^8+42x^7+53x^6-160x^5+118x^4+22x^3-56x^2-20x+74\geq 0$$

I plotted the graph on Wolfram Alpha and found that the inequality seems to hold. I was unable to represent the polynomial as a sum of squares.

It looks quite boring to approximate the derivative to be zero and use some numerical methods to show that values near local minimums proves that the inequality really holds everywhere.

Comment: My goodness.... Where is this polynomial coming from? Have you got it in any other form? Is it a part of a larger problem? All I want to avoid is that this is an "XY problem" (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Did you already try [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83670/proving-that-a-polynomial-is-positive?rq=1)?

Comment: Someone asked that in https://keskustelu.suomi24.fi/t/15152227/polynomin-arvot . Wolfram alpha gave some other forms but nothing useful. I read that Sturm's theorem might work but I have no experience on that theorem.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I tried with computer but found only an approximate solution: $x^8-x^7+2x^6-2x^5+3x^4-3x^3+4x^2-4x+\frac{5}{2}\approx (x^4 - 0.500000000000000?*x^3 - 5.129859219215791?*x^2 + 2.185058039692294?*x + 1.076147198476765?)^2+(3.465504067005489?*x^3 - 1.659206723790892?*x^2 - 3.756402880375866?*x + 1.158407185410471?)^2$

Comment: The polynomials in your question, in your link and in your last comment are all different. So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: The polynomial in your last comment is easily done using AM-GM or completing squares left to right, as only odd terms are negative, and coefficients are modest. The problem you posted is very different though.

Comment: @ProfessorVector That is an approximate solution to the inequality in the link  Dietrich Burde's post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x<0$ it's obvious.

But for $x\geq0$ we obtain:
$$58x^{10}-42x^9+11x^8+42x^7+53x^6-160x^5+118x^4+22x^3-56x^2-20x+74=$$
$$=(x^3-x^2-x+1)(58x^7+16x^6+85x^5+85x^4+207x^3+47x^2)+$$
$$+287x^4-138x^3-103x^2-20x+74>0,$$
where $$287x^4-138x^3-103x^2-20x+74=$$
$$=(16x^2-4x-5)^2+(31x^4-10x^3+x^2)+(40x^2-60x+49)>0.$$

Comment: You might want to add why $287 x^4 - 138 x^3 - 103 x^2 - 20 x + 74 $ is positive for $0 < x < 1.$ It really is obvious for $x \geq 1,$ as $287 > 138+103+20 = 261,$ and with $x \geq 1$ we do have $x^4 \geq x^3 \geq x^2 \geq x \geq 1$

Comment: I added my proof. See now.

Comment: $100 - 124 = -24, \;  $  $3600 - 4 \cdot 41 \cdot 49 = 3600 - 8036 = -4436$

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: I don't see. Wolfram alpha gave $(16x^2-4x-5)^2+(31x^4-10x^3+x^2)+(41x^2-60x+49)=287x^4-138x^3-102x^2-20x+74$.

Comment: It was typo. I fixed. See now.

Answer (score 3):

A sum-of-squares decomposition is given by $z^TQz$ where $z = (1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5)$ and  the positive definite matrix $Q$ is

$Q = \begin{bmatrix}    
    74 &  -10  & -38  &   9  &   8  & -30\\
   -10 &   20  &   2  &  -8  & -22  &   9\\
   -38 &    2  & 118  & -28  & -40  &  21\\
     9 &   -8  & -28  & 115  &   0  & -32\\
     8 &  -22  & -40  &   0  &  75  & -21\\
   -30 &    9  &  21  & -32  & -21  &  58
\end{bmatrix}$

Found by solving an integrality constrained sum-of-squares problem (i.e., mixed-integer semidefinite program) in the MATLAB Toolbox YALMIP

```
sdpvar x
p = 58*x^10-42*x^9+11*x^8+42*x^7+53*x^6-160*x^5+118*x^4+22*x^3-56*x^2-20*x+74;
z = monolist(x,5);
Q = sdpvar(6);
optimize([integer(Q),coefficients(z'*Q*z-p,x)==0,Q>=0],sum(sum(Q)));
```

Comment: Can YALMIP get SOS for (a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-3*(a^3*b+b^3*c+c^3*a)? I try the code in https://i.imgur.com/qImKSl6.png but the result seems to be wrong.

Comment: I don't think there is any integer sos. If you solve the standard problem (i.e. use solvesos or manually and skip integer) the solution contains fractions. Use z'*Q*z-2*p instead and it finds a solution, i.e. allow integers and ratios involving halfs

Comment: I use solvesos, but it didn't give the fraction form, sir. For example, in some inequality, it gives 0.5783.. or 0.5000. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Of course, solvesos does not work with integer factorizations. You have to use the manual setup, and then study the polynomial 2*p and show that it is sos, i.e. match the coefficients of  z'Qz-2*p with Q integer

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but can YALMIP tool get SOS with sqrt sign?

Comment: sqrt is not polynomial so it makes no sense in that setting, so if you have it you must reformulate the problem to something polynomial i.e. replacing z^0.5 with u and then perform the sos over the set z^2=u and z>=0

Comment: I mean sqrt sign here is.., for example: $\sqrt{2},..$

Comment: that would be a completely symbolic tool (i.e. not numerical sos) as it cannot even be expressed numerically